# What does "gandmelon" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In season 1 episode 13 of simpson a news anchor says

> There is an overturned melon truck on the interstate. Oh it's a mess.
>   There is lots of rubber neck in **gandmelon wrestling** going on, so
>   expect delays--

What does the bold part mean?

Comment: "Rubber-necking and melon-wrestling"

Comment: [Lady Mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)

Comment: @CowperKettle: The late John Ciardi, American poet and translator of Dante, mentioned that one of his students thought he had said "fantasy echo" when he used the French phrase *fin de siècle*.

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated above, it seems you have misinterpreted the reporter.

The phrase is "rubbernecking and melon-wrestling."

Rubbernecking means to stare at something foolishly. It's often used to describe people in traffic as they drive past an accident on the highway. When you rubberneck, you usually slow down and cause the traffic to worsen.

*Melon wrestling* refers to people struggling to remove the melons from the road.

Comment: I don't think melon-wrestling is between people in a pile of melons. Consider this [definition of wrestle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrestle) : to engage in or as if in a violent or determined struggle *wrestling with cumbersome luggage* I think it was meant to describe a scene of people struggling to get the melons cleaned up.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense!